# Approx after how many days after getting Notice of Recordation, patent will be visible to public

Tags: uspto, pct

On the website https://patentcenter.uspto.gov/ search by PCT results with a following error message

*Sorry, the entered PCT Number 'PCT/US2023/XXXXXX' is not available. The number may have been incorrectly typed, or assigned to an application that is not yet available for public inspection.*

How long do we have to wait when the patent will be visible for public inspection?

Comment: I assume you checked your typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *granted patent* is almost immediately available for public inspection, that is an inherent aspect of the grant.

Patent *applications* are published 18 months after earliest claimed priority date. This is the case for PCT applications and most national applications. The U.S. allows a non-publication request under which applications are not published until and unless granted.

The question in the title may be different than in the body. I do not know what a “Notice of Recordation” is in a PCT context. In the US system recordation only refers to recordation of assignments, not of filing.